# Permissions for ECL provider

Tags: ecl, security

I have a new ECL provider which works perfectly when logged in as an Administrator. When an Author logs in, they don't see the new mount point.

Has anyone else seen this, and if so, what permissions do I need to set up to allow all users to view my new mount point?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Access to see the ECL mount point (and also write permissions to Tridion metadata) is controlled with the permissions for the stub folder. Unfortunately the stub folder is hidden for non-admins, so only admins can modify the permissions in the current release of ECL (yes, we know :) ). Notice you can control both read and write access here (who can update Tridion metadata). The provider can overlay it's own access rights for writing metadata and title separately.

For the Privileged user it does not really matter with regards to what the user see. Personally I would try to use the same user for all mount points on the system based on some potential future directions of ECL, but it is not a strict requirements. If you have a good reason to use different users, then do it... if you do not have a good reason to do one over the other, then choose to use the same user for all mountpoints. :)

Comment: Thanks Lars and Bart - My stub folder is in a system folder which did not have read rights for authors. Adding read rights solved the problem. 

This now means that the stub schema is now also visible to my author. Is there any way to hide this so it does not show up in the drop down list for new multimedia components?

Comment: @ChrisSummers nope, unfortunately there is no way to group or hide certain Schemas from authors (appart from denying them read rights which means they cannot use them).

Comment: Well, there is always the option to write a UI DataExtender filtering the schema out when the UI request a list of schemas.
Or the simple approach - rename it to something with "System use only" - it might be enough to stop most editors from using it.

Answer (score 4):

I have to confirm Jan's findings, when setting up an ECL provider, you specify a `PrivilegedUserName` for each mountpoint. If that user is a SDL Tridion Administrator, then your mountpoint should work for all SDL Tridion users.

For my mountpoints I always use the SDL Tridion Admin user for that, which also is a Administrator on server level. Depending on your ECL provider of course, but in general I don't think that would matter, as long as it is a SDL Tridion admin.

So besides from setting up a valid `PrivilegedUserName`, the only other requirement for each ECL provider is that your users have to have read rights on the Stub Folder(s) which you specified in the mountpoint configuration.

If your Authors don't have read rights on the stub folder, that will hide the mountpoint all together for them.

Comment: Thanks Bart. Bot you and Lars hit the nail on the head. I gave him the 'accept' as he needs the points more than you ;)

Comment: @ChrisSummers Super, I have to agree that his answer was more to the actual point (took me a while to figure that part out too ;o).

Answer (score 2):

All users should be able to see the mount point. I did a quick test for your and my provider is visible for non-admins too.

Maybe a provider (IContentLibrary) could do some user specific stuff in `public IContentLibraryContext CreateContext(IEclSession tridionUser)` but I don't think you can hide the mount point here.

Are you shure this is not a GUI caching issue or so?